# net::ERR_ACCESS_DENIED when opening video on SDcard

Tags: java, android

I am trying to play a video in a webview on a android tablet. I have hardcoded the path of the file in javascript: '/sdcard/Download/videoname.mp4'

I load that video in an HTML page. Everything works fine when I open the html page in a browser on the tablet. But I need to open the html page in a webview. When I do this I get the error net::ERR_ACCESS_DENIED. How could I get the right to open this video? This is a custom app that will be used on this tablet only. I have tried giving all authorizations I could to the webview:

```
WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);
WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webSettings.setAllowContentAccess(true);
webSettings.setAppCacheEnabled(true);
webSettings.setDomStorageEnabled(true);
webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
myWebView.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
myWebView.addJavascriptInterface(new WebAppInterface(this), "Android");
myWebView.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/androidtest.html");
```

And in the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Does anyone know how I could authorize my app to open the video (which again plays successfully when opening the html page directly in the browser)?

Comment: Can you try by adding this to your manifest file within the application tag: android:usesCleartextTraffic="true"
And then, re-install the app or clear the App data and run.

Comment: Yes I have seen and tried that already. It made no change. I've tried running the app from android studio and installed it on the tablet and got the same error in both cases.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how I solved it in the end. Perhaps a combination and rebuilding the project and rebooting the tablet, clearing data etc. But in the end what ended up working for me was just that:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

WebView myWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.webview);

WebSettings webSettings = myWebView.getSettings();
webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webSettings.setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);
```

The option `webSettings.setMediaPlaybackRequiresUserGesture(false);` is necessary to start the autoplay otherwise it just gets stuck on the "play" poster (triangle inside a circle).

I didn't need any other permission of manifest tag (although my webview loads a local html file).